# how to use sparks implicit conversion (e.g. $) in IntelliJ debugger evaluate expression

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

When debugging Spark/Scala code with IntelliJ, using e.g. `df.select($"mycol")` does not work in the evaluate expression window, while `df.select(col("mycol"))` works fine (but needs code change):

[image]

It says :

> Error during generated code invocation:
> com.intellij.debugger.engine.evaluation.EvaluateException: Error evaluating method : 'invoke': Method threw 'java.lang.NoSuchFieldError' exception.: Error evaluating method : 'invoke': Method threw 'java.lang.NoSuchFieldError' exception.

Strangely, it seems to work sometimes, especially if the `$` is already part of an existing expression in the code which I mark to evaluate. If I write arbitrary expressions (code-fragments), it fails consistently

EDIT: even repeating `import spark.implicts._` in the code-fragment window does not help

Comment: Did you `import spark.implicits._` ?

Comment: @mazaneicha yes i did

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this workaround:

```
import spark.implicits._
$""
df.select($"diff").show()
```

[image: before]

[image: after]

Comment: nice... seems unintuitive, but if its the only solution why not

Comment: using the single line `import spark.implicits.StringToColumn` at top of the code fragment works also (`$""` can be omitted then)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `import spark.implicits.StringToColumn` at top of the code fragment works

[image]

[image]

I think the reason is that IntelliJ does not realize that the import of the implicits is used in the first place (it is rendered gray), therefore its not available in the *evaluate expression* context

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similiar issue with NoSuchFieldError because of missing spark instance within the "Evaluate Expression" dialog. See example below.

```
class MyClass(implicit spark: SparkSession) {

  import spark.implicits._


  def myFunc1() = {
    // breakpoint here
  }
```

My workaround was to modify spark instance declaration in the constructor. I've changed "implicit spark" to "implicit val spark".
..and it works :)